# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, tuplas, typeerror

Si ya sé, perdón este es un error para google pero no le encuentro la solución, y como soy nuevo en *Python*, es posible que este teniendo un error conceptual grave.

Les dejo el código:

```
urlcrypto = requests.get(f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins").json()
    top10 = (0, 1, 2)
    criptogetter = urlcrypto[top10]["name"]+": "+locale.currency(urlcrypto[top10]["market_data"]["current_price"]["usd"])

case "cripto":
            return " TOP 10 Criptos "+'\n'+'\n'+criptogetter[top10[0]]
```

Realmente no entiendo el porque del error, es muy probable que este encarando el problema de la manera incorrecta, porque según leí, estos errores se dan cuando confundes un `(` o `[`, o te olvidas una coma... y no veo que eso este pasando...

Muchas gracias y disculpen por la pregunta tonta!!!

Comment: El código no tiene mucho sentido. ¿Qué es ese "case cripto:" que tienes por ahí? ¿Es parte de algo?

Comment: Es un bot de telegram, case "cripto" es en caso de que el comando que ponga el usuario sea /cripto. Lo que intento hacer es que me tire la cotizacion del top 3 de las cripto que figuran en la API.

Comment: Mejor publica el texto completo del mensaje de error, y también el trozo donde está la línea involucrada (como textos).